# Convert each image input to DataUrl or Base64 image while iterating

Tags: javascript

```
var toPush = []
for(var i = 1; i <= myVariable; i++){
     var variable1 = document.getElementById('q' + i).value;
     var var2 = document.getElementById(i + 'x').value;
     var var3 = document.getElementById(i + 'y').value;
     var var4 = document.getElementById(i + 'z').value;
     var var5 = document.getElementById(i + 'd1').value;
     var var6 = document.getElementById('xy' + i).value;
     var file = document.getElementById("fileup" + i);
     var twofour = [var2, var3, var4, var5];
                    
     let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file.files[0]);

        reader.onload = function () {
           pictureURL = reader.result;
        };
        reader.onerror = function (error) {
           console.log('Error: ', error);
        };
     toPush.push({"variable1": variable1, "twofour": twofour, "pictureURL": pictureURL} 
}
```

The application can add X many inputs by appending them do div. When it comes to pushing the data, I want to have the *file* input, which is the only image input, be read as DataURL, so it can show be used as a source to an image preview. I don't know if it is because of the iteration, but the *pictureURL* variable pushes as empty: in the database I got "pictureURL": "".

Is there any way around it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with this code. The reason that you're not receiving the `pictureUrl` is because you're reading it before it's ready.

`FileReader` reads the file asynchronously. It provides us a callback `onload` that is executed when it has read the file. We get the content of the file as `reader.result` only when this callback is executed. You have to rewrite your code to process the content of the file when it's either `FileReader.onload` or `FileReader.onerror` are executed.

See the working example below. I have removed unnecessary code. You can run the code by clicking on `Run code snippet` button at the bottom of the post

```js
function showIcons() {

    let files = document.querySelector('#files').files;

    if(files.length) {
        document.querySelector('#show-icons-error').textContent = "";
    } else {
        document.querySelector('#show-icons-error').textContent = 'No files have been selected';
    }

    let imageIcons = document.querySelector('#image-icons');
    imageIcons.innerHTML = '';

    let imageUrlArr = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        let imageIconHolder = document.createElement('img');
        imageIconHolder.classList.add('image-icon');
        imageIconHolder.setAttribute('image-index', i);

        imageIcons.appendChild(imageIconHolder);

        let file = files[i];

        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);

        reader.onload = function () {
            pictureURL = reader.result;
            imageIconHolder.src = pictureURL;
            
            imageUrlArr[i] = pictureURL;//Setting ith image, not pushing.
        };
        
        reader.onerror = function (error) {
            console.log(`Error loading image at index : ${i}, error: ${error}`);

            imageUrlArr[i] = error;//Error for ith image
        };
    }
}
```

```css
.image-icon {
    width: 10em;
    display: block;
    min-height: 5em;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <label for="files" class="btn">Select Images</label>
        <input id="files" type="file" value="Select File" accept="image/*" multiple="multiple">
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <div>
            <button id="show-icons" onclick="showIcons()">Show Icons</button>
            <span id='show-icons-error' style="color: red; font-weight: bold;"></span>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div id="image-icons">
            
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```